# Removing routes disposes Provider and throws error

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation, dispose, provider

To simplify my problem, I have 4 screens. Home screen, screen 2, screen 3, and screen 4. I initialize a Provider in screen 2, and when I navigate to screen 3, I pass the provider.

```
 Navigator.push(context, 
   MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (_) {
       return ChangeNotifierProvider<myProvider>.value(
        value: initializedProvider,
          child: Screen2()
          .
          .
```

When I navigate to screen 4 from screen 3 I do

```
        .. 
         return ChangeNotifierProvider<myProvider>.value(
           value: Provider.of<myProvider>(context, listen: false),
             child: Screen4()
```

When a user closes the app, I want to remove all routes and only display my login page. I do this by using

```
    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/login", (Route<dynamic> route) => false );
```

(I listen to the appLifecycleState change in the home page. That is where I start removing routes. )

I noticed that this removes the routes in what seems to be in random order every time I close the app. Sometimes screen 2 (where i initialize the provider) is removed first and that is when I get the error "Provider was used after being disposed". Im sure this is happening because screen 3 and 4 still have the provider when being disposed.

This error doesnt occur when screens are removed starting from the bottom (when screen 4 is removed, then screen 3, then screen 2, then home). I also dont want to wrap the change notifier around my material app.

Im new to Flutter so id like to know the best way to approach this. Ill rewrite this question if it needs more information or makes no sense. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you initialize the provider, in top of your widget tree which is in main.dart ?

Comment: I dont want to put it higher up the tree than necessary. Unless thats the standard for all providers. My problem is closing the app from any screen and the provider throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a provided class to the screens into Provider.value is an anti-pattern.
Place a single Provider above the all screens you want to access it (likely in main.dart).
The meaning of provider is to wrap your subtree into it and let your children widgets to access it. You shouldn't pass its value down.